# Problem in fetching data between two dates in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Here's my `tb_orders` table:

[image]

I want to fetch orders between date `2016-08-29` and `2017-01-14` including these mentioned dates.

I tried two queries using `AND` and `BETWEEN` operators but the result got is not as expected.

```
SELECT * FROM `tb_orders` WHERE `order_date` >= DATE('2016-08-29') AND `order_date` <= DATE('2017-01-14')
```

[image]

```
SELECT * FROM `tb_orders` WHERE `order_date` BETWEEN DATE('2016-08-29') AND DATE('2017-01-14')
```

[image]

I don't understand why am I not getting the record with date `2017-01-14`? Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below - as you are passing only date so you need to convert your order_Date column to date since your column data type is timestamp

```
SELECT * FROM `tb_orders` 
WHERE date(`order_date`) >= '2016-08-29' AND date(`order_date`) <= '2017-01-14'
```

Comment: Do not only write *You can try below*. Why OP should try it? What is the difference to the query OP provided and why should it work?

Comment: This cannot use an index. Surely that makes it downvote-worthy

Comment: I was exactly trying out this but unfortunately I applied `DATE()` to the value itself rather than the column name. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the timestamp. if you not put it in the date parameter it will be initialized with 00:00:00 and 2017-01-14 05:10:26 is later than 2017-01-14 00:00:00 .

use:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `tb_orders` 
WHERE `order_date` BETWEEN TIME('2016-08-29') AND TIME('2017-01-14 23:59:59'):
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple date function would do as below. Its short and precise.

```
Select * FROM tbl_orders
WHERE date(order_date) BETWEEN '2016-08-29' AND '2017-01-14'
```